# How to color some specific cells in HTMLTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I developed a training matrix for my company that shows all employees with all training courses provided in the company. Now, I have to develop it in such a way to be easy to edit and update by the admin. I did everything correct except one thing which is giving each group of courses a specific color (since I have 3 types of courses) starting from the fourth cell up to the last cell. FYI, I have two SqlDataSources for developing this matrix:

**SqlDataSource1 is for retrieving the GroupID:**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT [ID] FROM [groups]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**And the SqlDataSource2 will take the GroupID from the SqlDataSource1 and use it to generate the matrix:**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server"
                                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>"
                                            SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="kbiReport" FilterExpression="[Division] like '{0}%'">

                            <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:Parameter  Name="GroupID"/>
                            </SelectParameters>

                            <FilterParameters>
                                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlDivision" Name="DivisionName"
                                                         PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                            </FilterParameters>

            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Now, since I am using HTMLTable, I need to access the SqlDataSource1 to do some logic like:
if the GroupID = 1, then give this group Blue color and so on. I could be able to do that by doing the following:

My code-behind in C#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataView dv2 = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        foreach (DataRowView group in dv2)
        {
            SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters[0].DefaultValue = group[0].ToString();
            //create a new HtmlTable object
            HtmlTable table = new HtmlTable();

            DataView dv = (DataView)SqlDataSource2.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
            int columns = dv.Table.Columns.Count;
            int rows = dv.Count;

            //table's formating-related properties
            table.Border = 2;
            table.CellPadding = 3;
            table.CellSpacing = 3;
            table.Width = "900px";

            //to get the css style
            table.Attributes["class"] = "uGrid";

            //create a new HtmlTableRow and HtmlTableCell objects
            HtmlTableRow row;
            HtmlTableRow header = new HtmlTableRow();
            HtmlTableCell cell;


            //for adding the headers to the table
            foreach (DataColumn column in dv.Table.Columns)
            {
                HtmlTableCell headerCell = new HtmlTableCell("th");
                headerCell.InnerText = column.Caption;

                //The following if-else statements are for checking the GroupID and give each group
                //a specific color
                if (group[0].ToString().Equals("1"))
                    headerCell.BgColor = "lightBlue";
                else if (group[0].ToString().Equals("2"))
                    headerCell.BgColor = "lightYellow";
                else if (group[0].ToString().Equals("3"))
                    headerCell.BgColor = "Orange";

                //the header cells to the header
                header.Cells.Add(headerCell);
            }
            table.Rows.Add(header);

            //loop for adding rows to the table
            foreach (DataRowView datarow in dv)
            {
                row = new HtmlTableRow();
                //row.BgColor = "yellow";


                //loop for adding cells
                for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                {
                    cell = new HtmlTableCell();
                    if (j < 4)
                    {
                        cell.InnerText = datarow[j].ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox();

                        int checkBoxColumns = dv.Table.Columns.Count - 5;
                        string fieldvalue = datarow[j].ToString();
                        string yes = fieldvalue.Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
                        string courseid = fieldvalue.Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
                        checkbox.ID = row.Cells[3].InnerText + "," + courseid.Trim();
                        checkbox.Checked = yes.Equals("Yes");
                        cell.Controls.Add(checkbox);

                    }

                    //add the cell to the current row
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);
                }

                //add the row to the table
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            //add the table to the page
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(table);

        }
    }
```

There is a different number of courses in each group but the coloring should be started from the fourth cell up to the last cell. I did many tries in the following part of the above code but I failed and I don't know why. **So how to do that?**

```
//for adding the headers to the table
            foreach (DataColumn column in dv.Table.Columns)
            {
                HtmlTableCell headerCell = new HtmlTableCell("th");
                headerCell.InnerText = column.Caption;

                //The following if-else statements are for checking the GroupID and give each group
                //a specific color
                if (group[0].ToString().Equals("1"))
                    headerCell.BgColor = "lightBlue";
                else if (group[0].ToString().Equals("2"))
                    headerCell.BgColor = "lightYellow";
                else if (group[0].ToString().Equals("3"))
                    headerCell.BgColor = "Orange";

                //the header cells to the header
                header.Cells.Add(headerCell);
            }
            table.Rows.Add(header);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would solve it using a ListView control to build the html table. Using ListView control you have access to the OnItemDataBound property which you can use to write your code to color the specific row you need.